# Java Multithread File Read + Operation + Write

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a small program to solve the following problems using multithreading in java.  I am struggling to even understand where to start, and am looking for some advice.  The desired steps in the process are as follows:

1. Read in all the text files contained within a given directory
2. Create a word count for each one of the files read.
3. Write the count of words as an output to a new file in a different directory.

I have written the wordcount function, and that works fine, but would like to know more about how to multithread this operation so that the files are read, the words counted, and then the output is all written in parallel.

Comment: Perhaps using Stream functionality in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).  Create a List of files contained within the directory, and get a parallelStream of those File objects.  Then you can process each file, returning the word count as part of the parallel stream processing.  Then you can figure out what to do with the count... if each is written to their own file, that too could be part of the stream processing.  I'd start there

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the single threaded version? Conceptually it can be as simple as this (pseudo Java code). countWords and writeOutput are your methods and 
files is a list of files you already read in.

```
files.parallelStream()
    .map(file -> new Pair(file, countWords(file)))
    .forEach((file, count) -> writeOutput(file, count));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your enthusiastic in learning multi-threaded programming!
Beside parallel your task between files, you can also parallel and optimize the actual countWords task.

This is a classic case for using Fork/Join. A rather advance level of multi-threaded programming but a very satisfying one :)

you can search the web for examples similar to your own, here is a one to start with: https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join